# How does network card pass signal to Ethernet?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

**disclaimer**: app dev asking networking question! :)

**my assumptions**

- network card is the last piece of hardware on the host to touch outgoing packets before they pass onto the network
- Ethernet can be copper or fiber

**question**

- how does network card handle passing packets to physically different Ethernet i.e. are network cards coupled to only work for either copper cabling or fiber cabling?

**guess at answer**

- some network cards work w/ [100BASE-TX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-TX) (copper)
- some network cards work w/ [100BASE-SX/LX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#Varieties) (fiber)
- some network cards work with only copper or only fiber

inspiration for post: was watching PluralSight course (*Network Interface Layer and Ethernet Operation for Cisco CCNA 200-125*) and the author said:

> "When we're talking about the network interface cards and fiber
>   optics, the network interface card here is a laser, these laser types
>   are going to vary depending upon the type of Ethernet we're using."

Comment: I really don't understand your question... are you wanting to know how a card converts the packets of data to ones & zeros and then sends them as standardized electrical signals or light pulses? From what perspective, since that usually isn't a concern for application development or users, it is handled at physical or data link layer of the OSI model, outside of the realm of applications.

Comment: Cheers for the good question. I'm trying to better understand how network cards are/are not coupled to Ethernet mediums. Which is definitely in layer 1 of the OSI. The reason I posted here is because I originally posted on Stack Overflow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827191/how-does-network-card-pass-signal-to-ethernet] and one of the moderators pointed out Super User would be a better location for a question so far down the OSI.

Comment: "how network cards are/are not coupled to Ethernet mediums" is actually the confusing part... the cards are engineered to a specific set of recognized standards, a specialized processor on the card takes the data packets and converts them to a standardized protocol, whether it be light or electrical impulses. A detailed answer could involve dozens to hundreds of pages of text depending on the technical depth.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY_(chip)

Comment: @DanielB Cheers, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as physical network cable connections go, Ethernet  cards fall into 3 categories:

1. Most have a copper interface (RJ-45 / 8P8C), for doing 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX, 1000BASE-T, or 10GBASE-T. These connect to unshielded twisted pair (UTP) copper cables. Cat3 for 10BASE-T, Cat5 or better for 100 & 1000BASE-T, Cat6 or better (if I recall correctly) for 10GBASE-T. This kind of card cannot connect directly to fiber.
2. Some have a dedicated fiber interface. Thus a 1000BASE-SX card would be different from a 1000BASE-LX card. This kind of card cannot connect directly to copper.
3. Some cards, plus the built-in Ethernet interfaces of many servers, switches, routers, and other network equipment, will have a receptacle for a pluggable module for the physical cable interface (SFP, QSFP, etc.). These cards/ports can connect to any kind of cable, but you have to match the pluggable module to the cable type.

Comment: Cheers for the help! If I understand you correctly: twisted pair cabling interfaces w/ a host using RJ-45/8P8C connectors (made of copper) but the cabling itself is Cat 6/5e/5 (which requires fiber). Is there some translation process between the two? I'm confused how the signal comes off the network card via copper and is then transmitted via glass.

Comment: @ZachValenta I don't think you grasp some of the terms here. CAT-6/5e/5 cabling is a copper cabling standard, not fiber. If the signal is going from traditional copper Ethernet to fiber, a transceiver is required, sometimes it is a stand-alone device and sometimes it is a module in a switch or even a dedicated card.

Comment: @ZachValenta I edited my answer to make it more clear because it sounds like you got the wrong impression from my first version.

Comment: @Spiff To paraphrase Twain, I asked a convoluted question because I didn't understand enough to ask a simple one :) "If the signal is going from traditional copper Ethernet to fiber..." --> this transition, when the medium carrying the signal transitions from copper to fiber and (roughly) where/how that happens, is what I was after. I appreciate your explanations; seeing the question more clearly as a result

Answer (score 0):

The network cards include (in the very last "stage") some hardware components that convert electrical signals to optical signals (fiber) or couple/amplify the electrical signals so they can be transmitted over twisted pair, coax etc.

These hardware parts are very different. E.g. you can't plug in an optical medium (fiber) into an electrical socket.

So to connect LANs with a different physical medium, you either need network cards or similar devices with *all* of the involved "last stage" hardware, so this device will have several ports with different physical medium. Or you need several different network cards.

In other words, the answer to "how does a network card handle passing packets to physically different Ethernet" is "it usually doesn't".

Comment: Your answer is helping me a lot; thanks! I am a little confused by one point, however; you start with "network cards include (in the very last "stage") some hardware components that convert electrical signals to optical signals (fiber)" but close saying that a network card typically doesn't interpose between different physical medium. Can you speak a little more on where in the flow from LAN to MAN to WAN electrical signal turns to optical?

Comment: Typically, you have routers (that is, dedicated hardware, not single ethernet cards) that have both optical ports (with corresponding hardware) and electrical ports (with corresponding hardware). Or if you are talking DSL: Your home router has LAN ports and one DSL port (again, different hardware), and after the DSLAM on the other end there is provider equipment that connects the DSLAM to the provider's optical fiber network. Etc.

Comment: Cheers! This is very helpful.